# Bootstrap data-toggle not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, twig

First off, yes this question has been asked a million times but no answer has fixed my issue.

When I open my page, the active tab shows along with the table associated with it.

GOOD

When I click the other tab, a table associated with that tab shows up UNDER my original table. (So both tabs are now active and displaying, even though the current selected one is the only one that should be)

BAD

Now both tables are shown. There are no errors in the console. I include jquery before js. I've tried to use jquery functions as well, even though it's not needed, and no change.

How can I fix this?

```
{% block body -%}

    <h1 class="text-center">Product List</h1>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li role="navigation" class="active">
                <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" href="#tab1">Category: Food</a>
            </li>
            <li role="navigation">
                <a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" href="#tab2">Category: Other</a>
            </li>  
        </ul>

{% for category in categories %}

    <div class="tab-content">

        {% if category.categoryName == 'Food' %}
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" >
        {% else %}
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2" >
        {% endif %}           

                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for entity in category.products %}
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="{{ path('product_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
                                <td>{{ entity.name }}</td>
                                <td>${{ entity.price }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entity.quantity }}</td>
                                {% for description in entity.descriptions %}
                                    <td>{{ description.productDesciption }}</td>
                                {% endfor %}
                                <td>
                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{ path('product_cart', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Add Product To Cart</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p> -- </p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{ path('product_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Show</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <p> -- </p>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="{{ path('product_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Edit</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}   
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div><!-- Ends tab2 TAB -->
            </div><!-- Ends tab1 -->

    </div><!-- Ends tab-content -->

{% endfor %}

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ path('product_new') }}" role="button">Create a New Entry</a>

{% endblock %}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/USERALPHA32/s63LLmaq/

Comment: Any possibility you could provide a jsbin or jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I can try but I can't guarantee anything. I'm using Twig. Give me a few

Comment: Flatten the twig template into HTML. You shouldn't need twig or PHP to demonstrate this problem right? It's all HTML and CSS. As we don't have your data, we can't recreate your plain HTML to see the problem.

Comment: yes but I generate content using for loop. I've tried to replicate however things work correctly. I assume it's due to the loop but I cannot figure out why

Comment: View source and paste it into jsbin or jsfiddle or here. The loops are irrelevant, until we can see the final output of the template.

Comment: Your loop should not include the tab-content div, start it after tab-content and close it at the end of the panel you're looping over.

Comment: @vanburen this just displays the tables together from the start

Comment: Check your output because it looks like you have an extra closing div which may be causing this: `</div><!-- Ends tab2 TAB --></div><!-- Ends tab1 -->`. I would think you only need one, not both inside the loop.

Comment: I wish it was that simple, unfortunately this makes no change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two tab-content when there should only be one.

```
<div class="tab-content">
```

Simply move your second tab-panel to your first tab-content div. And then remove the second unnecessary tab-content div.

Here's the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s63LLmaq/1/).

Comment: If I move my tab-content outside of my for loop, then both tables are shown and the functionality is broken. I see your fiddle working but the solution you provided cannot be done with twig. I hope you know what I mean

Comment: You can use a style="display:none;" on tab-panels EXCEPT the first one.